# Can I put thick film chip resistors in parallel to increase the power rating?

Tags: power, resistors

I am looking at thick film chip resistors. If a 2512 resistor has a 2W power rating, can I parallel two to get 4W total power rating?

Will the heating of the resistors increase resistance so as to automatically balance the current?

Comment: Note that if you are relying on the PCB to dissipate heat and you put these next to each other, it won't help with heat dissipation.

Comment: If available on the board, a heat spreader layer would help. Probably cheaper to just spread them out more unless the board is already expensive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is fairly commonly done; two identical resistors can be put in parallel or in series to equally share power between them. If you use four (two series, two parallel), you can even have each one be the same resistance as the desired overall resistance, which may be convenient.

Most materials have a positive temperature coefficient of resistance, which means they'll balance out and share the load evenly. Semiconductors have a negative temperature coefficient, but they're not used for making resistors, except where a negative tempco is desired, e.g. for NTC thermistors.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can do this. However, it’s best to put them in series, in case one resistor overheats and fails open it will disconnect the second one. That won’t be the case if they’re parallel: one would fail, then the next would be taking the entire load and would eventually fail as well.

The series case where one fails is less likely to result in a fire.

Comment: Thanks for the failure mode tip!

Comment: Note that you get double the power **only** if they're physically far enough apart that they aren't heating each other up. This is easier to do with a series connection, which is another reason to go that way.